# need help in database integrity

Tags: asp.net, c++, sql-server

I need help executing a bat file from asp.net 2.0 and c++.

How to import runtime Sql Server2000 data into Oracle 9i?

How to manage project?

Comment: How is this related to Delphi?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle and SQL can talk replication/subscriptions.  Otherwise you can use standard SSIS/ETL methods such as BCP, SQLLDR, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's a real combo of question

Try to be more especific and/or separate in different questions